# convert Long[] to long[] (primitive) java

Tags: java

How do i convert Long[] to long[]? For example i know how to convert if it is not array as below.

```
long ll = (Long)Object[1].longValue()
```

But how do i convert for an array, the below is not right but can anyone correct it?

```
long[] l_ar = (Long[])Object[]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this? The most common reason you would use a `long[]` instead of a L`ong[]` is to save space and for performance reasons. If you already have the `Long[]`, what is it that you're trying to do? Or are you just curious?

Comment: @Falmarri: One use would be if you have a `Long[]`, but you're passing it to some function that expects a `long[]`.

Comment: @cHao: Right. In my experience that situation just doesn't come up very often, so I was just curious what the OP's situation is.

Answer (score 45):

You could steal a solution based on `ArrayUtils`

```
Long[] longObjects = { 1L, 2L, 3L };
long[] longArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(longObjects);
```

Comment: Link to the class:  [ArrayUtils.toPrimitive](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive(java.lang.Long[]))

Answer (score 21):

There are **no** standard API method for doing that (how would `null`-elements be handled?) so you would need to create such a method yourself.

Something like this *(will throw `NullPointerException` on any object beeing `null`)*:

```
public static long[] toPrimitives(Long... objects) {

    long[] primitives = new long[objects.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
         primitives[i] = objects[i];

    return primitives;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

using java 8 streams:

```
public static long[] unboxed(final Long[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
                 .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to do this, the best way would be to navigate through each array.

For instance, going from Long[] to long[]:

```
Long[] objLong = new Long[10];
//fill objLong with some values
long[] primLong = new long[objLong.length]

for(int index = 0; index < objLong.length; index++)
{
    primLong[index] = objLong[index];
}
```

Due to auto-unboxing, this should work out by converting Long to long.