# Removing an element from a primitive array

Tags: java, arrays, primitive-types

I have a primitive type array from which I want to remove an element at the specified index. What is the correct and efficient way to do that?

I am looking to remove the element in the way mentioned below

```
long[] longArr = {9,8,7,6,5};
int index = 1;

List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(longArr));
list.remove(index);
longArr = list.toArray(); // getting compiler error Object[] can't be converted to long[]
```

but the above approach looks to work with with Object only not with primitives.

Any alternative to that? I can not use any third party/additional libraries

Comment: Try declaring your list as a `List<Long>` instead of just a `List`.

Comment: already tried List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(longArr)) . It is giving compiler error "no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(List<long[]>)"

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029515/convert-long-to-long-primitive-java

Comment: Essentially you're running into boxing/unboxing issues (converting `long` primitives to and from `Long` objects).

Comment: @Nishit You are not allowed to do that. Because your `ArrayList` is referencing the `Array` and changing the `Array` will laos change the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a new array and copy the elements; e.g. something like this:

```
public long[] removeElement(long[] in, int pos) {
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= in.length) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(pos);
    }
    long[] res = new long[in.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(in, 0, res, 0, pos);
    if (pos < in.length - 1) {
        System.arraycopy(in, pos + 1, res, pos, in.length - pos - 1);
    }
    return res;
}
```

NB: the above has not been tested / debugged ....

You could also do the copying using for loops, but `arraycopy` should be faster in this case.

The `org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.remove(long[], int)` method most likely works like the above code.  Using that method would be preferable ... if you were not required to avoid using 3rd-party open source libraries.  (Kudos to @Srikanth Nakka for knowing / finding it.)

The reason that you can't use an list to do this is that lists require an element type that is a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by StephenC, have a look at https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Arrays/arrays.html.

It explains java arrays pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Use org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.

```
long[] longArr = {9,8,7,6,5};
int index = 1;
longArr=ArrayUtils.remove(longArr, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[] {100,150,200,300};

List<Integer> filtered = Arrays.asList(arr).stream()
    .filter(item -> item < 200)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```